# Connection String for Netezza OLE DB by pyodbc.connect()

Tags: python-2.7, pyodbc, netezza

I have tried the following **connection string** with `pyodbc.connect()`

```
DRIVER={NZOLEDB};SERVER=myserver;PORT=xxxx;DATABASE=mydatabase;UID=myUID;PWD=mypassword;
```

But the following error message keeps coming up:

```
Error: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

What should the correct connection string be written?

Comment: As the name suggests, `NZOLEDB` is an OLEDB provider, not an ODBC driver. You'll need to install the NetezzaSQL ODBC driver and then use `Driver={NetezzaSQL}` as illustrated [here](https://www.connectionstrings.com/netezzasql-odbc-driver/).